# Is it possible to analyse session aborts from the Microsoft SQL Server side?

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

We see SQL session aborts on some clients. In most cases it is a real network problem (VPN/WLAN/Internet Connection).

Is it possible to see any reason code on the server side, when a session aborts?

I tried to use the SQL Server Profiler. I can see the Audit Logon/Logout, but there is no error code, if I just terminate the program or just cut of the network connection.